# ARM templates, Make an Http request

Tags: azure-rm-template

I was looking into adding a step that makes an HTTP request from ARM templates after I finish the swapping operation. Is it something doable using ARM templates?

Comment: What is the "swapping operation"?

Comment: I first deploy to a staging slot and then swap to the production slot

Comment: Do I get you right, that you perform the "swapping" in the ARM template by setting the `targetBuildVersion` of the production slot?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

ARM templates have no build-in methods to perform HTTP requests. If you absolutely must call an HTTP endpoint from your template, you can deploy a [deployment script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template) resource. This is a temporary container resource that executes a script and can be configured to be automatically removed after it ran sucessfully. In your case that might be a lot of infrastructure overhead for very little function.

An alternative approach would be to use your ARM template to deploy an [Event Grid event subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/2020-04-01-preview/systemtopics/eventsubscriptions?tabs=json). The event subscription can be configured to call a webhook or an Azure Function **every time** a slot swap is completed successfully on your app:

Here is an example:

```json
"resources": [
{
    "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics",
    "apiVersion": "2020-10-15-preview",
    "name": "{{ SYSTEM_TOPIC_NAME }}",
    "location": "{{ LOCATION  }}",
    "properties": {
        "source": "{{ RESOURCE_ID_OF_APP }}",
        "topicType": "Microsoft.Web.Sites"
    }
},
{
    "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics/eventSubscriptions",
    "apiVersion": "2020-10-15-preview",
    "name": "{{ SYSTEM_TOPIC_NAME }}/{{ EVENT_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME }}",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventGrid/systemTopics', '{{ SYSTEM_TOPIC_NAME }}')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "destination": {
            "properties": {
                "maxEventsPerBatch": 1,
                "preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes": 64,
                "endpointUrl": "{{ WEBHOOK_URL }}"
            },
            "endpointType": "WebHook"
        },
        "filter": {
            "includedEventTypes": [
                "Microsoft.Web.SlotSwapCompleted"
            ],
            "enableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays": true
        },
        "labels": [],
        "eventDeliverySchema": "EventGridSchema",
        "retryPolicy": {
            "maxDeliveryAttempts": 30,
            "eventTimeToLiveInMinutes": 1440
        }
    }
}
]
```